# I have 2 columns with <div> and the widths keep edging each other out

Tags: html, css, width, padding

What ends up happening is that the two columns cannot cohabitate next to each other without shrinking the width by about 2%. Doing that causes the edges to not align with the header and it just looks off. Is there something I am missing about 'width' or 'padding'?

This is what I am trying to emulate: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_blog_layout.asp

This is what ends up happening (before changing the width by -2%):

[image: Leaving left column at 75% and right column at 25%]

What happens when I have to change the width:

[image: After changing width by -2%]

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.header {
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
}

.leftcolumn {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
}

.rightcolumn {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.card {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.footer {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

@media(max-width: 800px) {
  .leftcolumn,
  .rightcolumn {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h2>Harry's Den</h2>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="leftcolumn">
    <div class="card">
      <h2>I love the World</h2>
      <h5>Helloo!</h5>
      <p>Text!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Wow this works so far!</h2>
      <h5>I am just happy to have a semi-functional blog!</h5>
      <p>Yay! I do not have much to say other than I am happy to have made it this far. Hopefully this will help!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightcolumn">
    <div class="card">
      <h2>About Me!</h2>
      <p>University: Texas Tech University</p>
      <p>Major: Computer Engineering (BS)</p>
      <p>Minor: Mathematics</p>
      <p>Interests: Energy Infrastructure and Space Exploration Efforts</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h3>Popular Post</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h3>Follow Me!</h3>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/account">Twitter</a>
      <br/>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/account">Facebook</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <h2>Developed by Barry Allen</h2>
  <h2>Quantum Enterprise Projects</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Padding and border are counted in the width. So you have to subtract them.

In your case you can do

```
.rightcolumn {
    width: calc(25% - 20px); 
}
```

Comment: sorry I didn't understand your question

Comment: Is this something I have to do for coding in the future or is it just my browser being special?

Comment: @hevansa98 yes you have to do it in the future too (or any other solution).

Comment: Take a look at this:
> Important: When you set the width and height properties of an element with CSS, you just set the width and height of the content area. To calculate the full size of an element, you must also add padding, borders and margins.

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Answer (score 3):

Here is the information from the MDN Web Doc.

> By default in the CSS box model, the width and height you assign to an
>   element is applied only to the element's content box. If the element
>   has any border or padding, this is then added to the width and height
>   to arrive at the size of the box that's rendered on the screen. This
>   means that when you set width and height you have to adjust the value
>   you give to allow for any border or padding that may be added.
>
> The box-sizing property can be used to adjust this behavior:
>
> - content-box gives you the default CSS box-sizing behavior. If you set    an element's width to 100 pixels, then the element's content
>     box will    be 100 pixels wide, and the width of any border or padding
>     will be    added to the final rendered width.
> - border-box tells the browser to    account for any border and padding    in the values you specify for    width and height. If you
>     set an    element's width to 100 pixels, that    100 pixels will
>     include any    border or padding you added, and the    content box
>     will shrink to    absorb that extra width. This typically    makes it
>     much easier to    size elements.

You have to use `box-sizing:border-box` to include border, padding and margin everything included in the width of your element.

Read more information in [**MDN Web Docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

```
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
    padding: 20px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
}
.header{
    padding: 30px;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
}
.leftcolumn{
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
}
.rightcolumn{
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.card{
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.row:after{
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.footer{
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
@media(max-width: 800px){
    .leftcolumn, .rightcolumn{
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
        <h2>Harry's Den</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="leftcolumn">
            <div class="card">
                <h2>I love the World</h2>
                <h5>Helloo!</h5>
                <p>Text!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <h2>Wow this works so far!</h2>
                <h5>I am just happy to have a semi-functional blog!</h5>
                <p>Yay! I do not have much to say other than I am happy to have made it this far. Hopefully this will help!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rightcolumn">
            <div class="card">
                <h2>About Me!</h2>
                <p>University: Texas Tech University</p>
                <p>Major: Computer Engineering (BS)</p>
                <p>Minor: Mathematics</p>
                <p>Interests: Energy Infrastructure and Space Exploration Efforts</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <h3>Popular Post</h3>      
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <h3>Follow Me!</h3>
                <a href="https://twitter.com/account">Twitter</a>
                <br/>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/account">Facebook</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <h2>Developed by Barry Allen</h2>
        <h2>Quantum Enterprise Projects</h2>
    </div>
```

Here is the Fiddle [**Link**](https://jsfiddle.net/w0b44dbr/1/). You can expand and shrunk the size of the screen and check it out how it is reacting.